# How to debug when program crashes on delete?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

When `delete` executes the program crashes. I tried following code to check for corrupted heap block but `if` condition results false.

```
int  rc;
if (_HEAPOK != (rc = _heapchk())) 
{
    switch(rc) 
    {
        case _HEAPEMPTY:
            puts("The heap has not been initialized.");
            break;
        case _HEAPBADNODE:
            puts("A memory node is corrupted or the heap is damaged.");
            break;
        case _HEAPBADBEGIN:
            puts("The heap specified is not valid.");
            break;
    }
}
```

complete code can be found here: http://cyberkinetica.homeunix.net/os2tk45/xpg4ref/157_L2__heapchkValidateDefa.html

Please let me know how to debug in this case.

EDIT:

I tried to debug in file:

`...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src\dbgheap.c`

and it's failing in following function:

`extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData)`

Comments on this function states:

***Purpose:*** Verify pointer is not only a valid pointer but also that it is from the 'local' heap. Pointers from another copy of the C runtime (even in the same process) will be caught.

what is this **local heap** and does it help in finding out the issue?

Comment: How to debug? Simplify. Pare the code down to the simplest example you can find that still exhibits the error. If the cause isn't obvious by then, post the whole thing. (Honestly, this is the answer so often that I can't understand why it isn't covered in first-year programming classes.)

Comment: 1.Write unit tests. 2. Don't use raw pointers, unless you really have to.

Comment: @Beta: it is first time i'm dealing with heap corruption. and i posted it here as the code block given in question gives the result as `_HEAPOK` so experts might have some suggestions i should follow. posting complete code is ... let me see if possible.

Comment: In general: Don't use `new`. Don't use `delete`. Use well-written, robust resource-managing containers if you must allocate dynamically. As a bonus, you will never have to spend nights writing `_heapchk()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to know why the code snippet is crashing in your posted link. The problem is in this line.

```
*(ptr - 1) = 'x'; // i.e. ptr[-1] = 'x';
```

After doing `ptr = malloc()`, you execute above command.
Pointer is writing in the memory area which is going **out of range**; which results in undefined behavior. Luckily the system crashes.

Comment: No. I used the code snippet to find if the heap in my program is valid or not. I didn't use complete code given in link but only the part posted.

Answer (score 1):

> How to debug when program crashes on delete?

Run it under Valgrind if you are on linux or with some other [Memory Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger) available on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging a debug-build, having source code, having VS installed - this is one of the easiest thing. Run the program within the debugger, and see where it is crashing. Check the call-stack and see where it leads.

For your problem, A bogus `delete` (not having `new`) may be the source of problem you are encountering. Check the code!